# Show difference between values of turning points of $ f(x) = (c-\frac{1}{c}-x)(4-3x^2) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

How would you show that the difference between the values of the turning points of

$$
f(x) = (c-\frac{1}{c}-x)(4-3x^2)
$$

is

$$
\frac{4}{9}(c+\frac{1}{c})^3
$$

$c>0$

I have attempted to compute the derivative and set it to $0$ (which is the standard approach), but things get messy (in my opinion).

Comment: What are the $x$'s corresponding to the turning points ? When you have them, compute the corresponding values of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with

$$f(x) = (c-\frac{1}{c}-x)(4-3x^2)$$

to make computation a bit more manageable, set $\boxed{\gamma=c-\frac{1}{c}}$, so

$$f(x)=4\gamma-4x-3\gamma x^2+3x^3$$

You had the correct idea to set $f'(x)=0$ at the turning points. So

$$f'(x)=-4-6\gamma x+9x^2=0\quad(\text{at turning points})$$

By the quadratic formula

$$x=\frac{6\gamma\pm\sqrt{36\gamma^2+144}}{18}=\frac{\gamma\pm\sqrt{\gamma^2+4}}{3}$$

At this stage, see if the quantity under the square root can be simplified:

$$\gamma^2+4=\left(c-\frac{1}{c}\right)^2+4=\left(c^2-2+\frac{1}{c^2}\right)+4=c^2+2+\frac{1}{c^2}=\left(c+\frac{1}{c}\right)^2$$

*Often this sort of simplification will work as the goal of such a question is not typically to test whether you can perform messy number crunching, e.g. computing $f(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt5})$.*

So the two roots are given by

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{\left(c-\frac{1}{c}\right)\pm\left(c+\frac{1}{c}\right)}{3} \implies x_1=-\frac{2}{3c},\:x_2=\frac{2c}{3}$$

I will omit the computation of $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.